# How to trigger a specific number in a range without triggering the range

Tags: python-3.x

Really simple and newby question, but how would  I run this without having it print both You have responsibilities and No one likes you?

> if age >= 20:
>       print('You have responsibilities')
>
> if age == 23:
>       print('No one likes you')

Answer (score 1):

```
if age == 23:
    print('No one likes you')
elif age >= 20:
    print('You have responsibilities')
```